# Edited images different in Mac and PC

Tags: gimp, image-editing, mac, windows

I am a total amateur at using image editing programs. I have been scanning pages from a book to my Mac (High Sierra) using Image Capture and saving it in png format. I have then used Gimp to edit pages to ensure that paragraphs stay together. For example I will resize an image so as to create space at the top of the page, then copy and paste a partial paragraph from the previous page into that space as a new layer. The image of the page is then saved by either exporting it as a png file under a new name, or saving it over the existing file.

I then paste the resulting image into a web page and upload it. What is strange is that, viewing the web page on line, the image that appears when viewed on a Mac is the EDITED image, whereas in Windows 7 the OLD UNEDITED image appears. That is, the Mac sees the new page resulting from the cut and paste operation, while the Windows machine sees the original image. I find this behaviour bizarre. What am I doing wrong?

This is the image: http://www.cjvlang.com/mlessons/images/shugden38.png

Comment: Wouldn't OCR be a convenient option for you? If your scans are all text-only the result could then be imported in Word or any other word-processor to allow free formatting. Some OCR software even tries to match fonts and document format.

Comment: I'm not sure OCR can read Mongolian.

Comment: Update. I've tried newocr and it appears to work for Mongolian. As long as it can produce reliable output I'll try this approach instead. Thanks!

Comment: Of course newocr is an option too... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds merely like a **browser cache**.

Browsers save items to the local hard drive in order to load pages faster and not download things over and over and over again.

If the *name* of your image file is not changing, that's more of an indicator the cache may be what you are seeing. If a browser downloads and displays "My_Image.png", then you edit the image and upload it to the same page again, and it's still titled "My_Image.png" the browser may *think* it's the same image and therefore merely display the image it has in its cache.

There are 2 easy ways around a browser cache other than merely disabling it (how to do that depends upon the browser.)

- Change the name of the name file. Rather than "My_Image.png" use "My_Image1.png" (or whatever). If the image name is different the browser will *not* think it's the same image, even if it actually is.
- Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click `Refresh` in the browser. This *forces* a fresh download of the web page and its contents for all browsers. Sometimes you may need to click refresh a couple times though.

Why the Mac sees a new image is because the old image wasn't loaded on the Mac prior to the changes. So, there's no cached image to load. The same thing can happen in reverse though. Mac browsers cache web content just like Windows browsers.

Comment: Thank you for that! It could be a cache issue, but maybe not a browser cache. The image was scanned to a Mac, edited on a Mac, then uploaded to a web server. It was viewed online using both the Mac and a totally separate Windows computer. The Windows computer was seeing it for the first time. Surely the cache issue could only be related to Gimp. The Mac saw the updated version and remembered it as it had been saved, even though it was on a web server. The Windows machine saw the image as it really was -- changes unsaved. I will now go with OCR; I hadn't realised how good it had got. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

For freely editing scanned text images it often is easier to make them text file by using an OCR software. The professional Mac software for this would be Abbyy FineReader but there are also Open Source software that can help your for free. See e.g.[this Q&A on our sister site Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76471/make-existing-pdf-searchable-ocr-via-command-line-script).

I tried your example image with the Open Source software **Tesseract** which has a Mongolian language plugin:

```
tesseract -l mon input.png output
```

This gave me below text file (entirely unedited because I could not even read the file) where you may just need to correct a few recognition errors.

> -Уучлаарай, гэгээнтээн. Бид энд таны санааг ингэтлээ зовоох гэж бус, та талийгаач шавийнхаа талаар, хийдээс гадуурхи амьдралынх нь талаар
>   хэр мэддэг байсныг л сонирхох гэж, мэддэг бол чухам юу юу мэддэг
>   байсныг л лавлах гэж ирсэн юм л даа хэмээн Шинингийн мөрдөн байцаагч
>   сандран шулганахад, Ордосоос ирсэн ахлах шинжээч шуудхан л:
>   -Дарамбал лам бурханы наймаа хийдэг байсныг та мэдэх үү? гэж асуулаа.      Сэрдог гэгээн тайвнаар:
>   -Мэдэхгүй ээ. Хийдийн хажууханд хар бор амьдралтай хот байна. Эргэл мөргөлийн хүмүүсийн өргөл барьцанд хүний номыг мартуулах хор шингэсэн
>   байх нь ч бий. Тиймээс над шиг хэр тааруу багшийн шавь нар өчүүхэн
>   олзонд хууртсан байхыг яаж мэдэх вэ. Ер нь одоо баян лам олширч шүү
>   дээ. Харин шавь нар минь баяжвал түүнээ надаас ёс мэт нуудаг юм.
>   Үнэтэй торгон дээлээ нуучихаад, хямд муу орхимж нөмөрч ирээд золгоно.
>   Тиймээс би нөхөөстэй оймстой ламтай таарсан ч “Амьдрах гэж цуглуулсан
>   зүйлс маань эргээд үхлийн шалтгаан болох нь ч бий” хэмээн сударт
>   өгүүлдэгийг л улигладаг юм даа гэлээ.      “Өөрийгөө талийгаач ламын
>   анд нөхөр гэж хэлсэн залуу лам энэ багшийгаа л хуулсан юм шиг дуурайж
>   дээ” гэж Ордосоос ирсэн ахлах шинжээч арга тасрангуй бодлоо. Энэ үед
>   Шинингийн мөрдөн байцаагч:
>   -Бидний олж мэдснээр бол, талийгаач Балба, Түвдээс бурхан авчруулж Монгол руу гарган арилжаалдаг байжээ. Ихээхэн-ашиг олдог байсан
>   бололтой. Тиймээс энэ наймааных нь хамтрагчдыг олбол хэргийн сэжүүр
>   олдох болов уу гэж таамаглаж байгаа юм гэхчлэн мөрдлөгийнхөө үүцээс
>   гөвж гарав.

In the link above there also is a link which shows you how to install it on a Mac. You will need to also install the Mongolian language pack.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried OCR -- Iris -- some years ago and swore off it because the results were so horrendous. (So are many PDFs of old books.) I hadn't realised they had improved so much. Thank you again!